# Mono: is changing the thread's priority supported?

Tags: c#, multithreading, mono, xamarin.android

I write my code in MonoDevelop and I want to try namespace of System.Threading. I wrote this simple code:

```
class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    System.Threading.Thread thread=new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(ThreadProc));
    Console.WriteLine(thread.Priority);//output current thread priority
    thread.Priority=System.Threading.ThreadPriority.Highest;//change thread priority
    Console.WriteLine(thread.Priority);//output current thread priority again
  }
  public static void ThreadProc() {
    //make some operations
  }
}
```

But I see this:
[image]

That is, the thread priority has not changed (OS: Ubuntu 12.10). How can I change the thread priority?

Comment: Give the thread some work. It starts and finishes extremely quickly, and you cannot change the poriority of a finished thread. ALso try to

Comment: He didn't start the thread yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing thread priorities has not yet been implemented.

See the [source code](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Threading/Thread.cs#L615) on github.

Comment: If anyone wants to try fixing this, I recommend looking at the WIP patch here so you don't start from scratch: https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=540524

Answer (score 1):

This has been recently implemented in Mono 4.4. [Relevant docs here](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/4.4.0/#implement-thread-priority-setting).